# To remove wireless driver in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, drivers, netgear

When I typed

```
ndiswrapper -l
bcmn43xx32 : driver installed
    device (0846:9020) present
bcmn43xx64 : driver installed
    device (0846:9020) present
```

I have two drivers. How can I remove 32bit version.
It is the driver for NETGEAR WNA3100.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing ndisgtk will solve your problem. It is a graphical frontend for NDISWrapper where you can add or remove drivers. I do not know the exact Broadcom chipset you have but if the components of the two is not relying on each other you can remove the 32-bit driver for sure.

[image: NDISGtk]

I hope I could help :)

Comment: If you found my answer helpful [please mark it as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks "ndisgtk is already the newest version." so I have that software. But how can I launch it?

Comment: @batuman As far as I remember sudo ndisgtk in terminal should work :)

Comment: @batuman or an another solution to run: 

    dpkg -L ndisgtk | grep /usr/bin 

It will search for ndisgtk, and if it is found run:

/usr/bin/<the-found-name>